# pronunciation of "femme" and "lemme" words

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, phonétique, euphonie

In french language, there are many words which syntax are the same. Normally these words will be pronunciated with the same way, but it is not the case, for example ,for :

1. Lemme
2. Femme

It is two similar words, but we pronunciated  `femme` like `fame`.

- What are the reasons of this difference?

Comment: What does syntax have to do with pronunciation?